# Virtual Attributes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, attributes, virtual

I am going through a ruby tutorial and trying to use understand how Virtual Attributes. This is the example shown in the tutorial.

```
class Spaceship
  def destination
    @autopilot.destination
  end

  def destination=(new_destination)
    @autopilot.destination = new_destination
  end
end

ship = Spaceship.new
ship.destination = "Earth"
puts ship.destination
```

As per tutorial, this code should ideally return Earth, but I am encountering the below error.

```
class.rb:7:in `destination=': undefined method `destination=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) from class.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

I am sorry but unable to identify the missing part.

Comment: What is `@autopilot` ? It is not being initialized..

Comment: Where you you initialize `@autopilot`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign your `@autopilot` variable something.

Something like this should work:

```
class Spaceship
  def initialize
    @autopilot = Struct.new(:destination).new(nil)
  end

  def destination
    @autopilot.destination
  end

  def destination=(new_destination)
    @autopilot.destination = new_destination
  end
end
```

But if you want to add a virtual attribute, then keep the value as a simple instance variable, like so:

```
class Spaceship
  def destination
    @destination
  end

  def destination=(new_destination)
    @destination = new_destination
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does this line does `@autopilot = Struct.new(:destination).new(nil)`

Comment: It created a new `Struct` with a `destination` property that has `nil` value. Run it in the console to checkout the output. On the same object, you can use `destination` and `destination=` methods.

Comment: I just googled about Struct, it creates a new class. But why do we need to have a new class to assign something to **@autopilot** variable. Forgive my ignorance on the topic. I am new to Ruby. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We don't need to do that. I was just getting your existing code to work. The second version is what you really want.

Comment: Oh okay. Well the [tutorial](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/ruby-fundamentals) which I am following has confused me. These are the example they have given for [Virtual Attributes](https://s3.amazonaws.com/FOREVER/Ruby_Virtual_Attri_Inst_Vars_1.png) and [Instance Variables](https://s3.amazonaws.com/FOREVER/Ruby_Virtual_Attri_Inst_Vars_2.png).

Comment: I've to sign-up to see the entire tutorial. Don't want to do that. But the code in the image of virtual attributes is simply incorrect - it's the same code you've shared.

Answer (score 1):

As [humza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2493089/humza) has pointed out, the code as written will not work.

I suspect the author meant to write something like the following, and wants to make the point that although `destination` looks like an attribute  (and we may send the message `destination` to an object and get the expected response),  *there is no corresponding instance variable @destination*.  We may think of `destination` as being a virtual attribute.

```
class Spaceship
  def destination 
    dosomething 
  end

  def destination=(new_destination)
    @autopilot = new_destination
  end

  def dosomething
    @autopilot
  end
end 

ship = Spaceship.new
ship.destination ="Earth"
puts ship.destination
```

Objects may behave as if the class Spaceship was written as shown in the next example, that is the interface of both classes is the same (and in this case we *do* have an instance variable `@destination`).

```
class Spaceship
  def destination
    @destination
  end

  def destination=(new_destination)
    @destination = new_destination
  end
end

ship = Spaceship.new
ship.destination ="Earth"
puts ship.destination
```

A message that is send to an object of the Class Spaceship does not need to know (and does not know) about the internal implementation.

Virtual Attributes are treated well [here](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html), and a better example is given, where a method `durationInMinutes` is defined without any corresponding instance variable `@durationInMinutes`. The explanation given is very concise, and I'll quote it in full:

> Here we've used attribute methods to create a virtual instance variable. To the outside world, durationInMinutes seems to be an attribute like any other. Internally, though, there is no corresponding instance variable.

The author(s) continue:

> This is more than a curiosity. In his landmark book Object-Oriented Software Construction , Bertrand Meyer calls this the Uniform Access Principle. By hiding the difference between instance variables and calculated values, you are shielding the rest of the world from the implementation of your class. You're free to change how things work in the future without impacting the millions of lines of code that use your class. This is a big win.